# jQuery use ajax and json to switch page with button

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi so I have a JS file with a function for my button, this button get value from different checkbox in a table. But now i want to get these value on another page (for invoice treatement).

Here is my Script :

```
$("#boutonfacturer").click(function () {

var checked = $('input[name="id_commande[]"]:checked');
var tab = [];
var jsonobj = {};
checked.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    jsonobj.value = value;
    tab.push(jsonobj);
});
         var data= { recup : tab };
         console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'genererfacture-facture_groupee.html',
                data: data,
                success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.error === 'OK') {
                    console.log('SUCCESS');
                } 
                else {
                    console.log('ERROR' + msg.error);
                }
        }

            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });

});
```

i use an MVC architecture so there is my controller :

```
public function facture_groupee() {

    $_POST['recup'];
    var_dump($_POST['recup']);
    console.log(recup);

    $this->getBody()->setTitre("Facture de votre commande");
    $this->getBody()->setContenu(Container::loader());
    $this->getBody()->setContenu(GenererFacture::facture_groupee());
```

and for now my view is useless to show.
I have probably make mistake in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind after thinking, I have used my ajax.php page which get my another page thanks to a window.location :

my JS :

```
$("#boutonfacturer").click(function () {

var checked = $('input[name="id_commande[]"]:checked');
var tab = [];
checked.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    tab.push(value);
});
var data = {recup: tab};
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php?action=facture_groupee',
    data: data,
    success: function (idfac) {
        console.log("Data Saved: " + idfac);
        var id_fac = idfac;
        window.location = "ajax.php?action=facture_groupee=" + id_fac;
    }

});
```

});

my php :

```
public function facture_groupee() {

    foreach ($_POST['recup'] as $p){
        echo $p; }
```